# Why i need to define table name everytime in WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, navicat

i was testing a software on my computer , i have a mysql installed on it . now i have transfered this software to a server . no any mysql command is working

for example this is the command that was working on my computer

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM camera WHERE stored=3;
```

when i try to execute it on my server here is the result

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stored=3' at line 1
```

but this one is working

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM camera WHERE camera.stored=3;
```

is there any way to restore it without needing to define the table name  ?

Comment: Tag your question properly!!!  MySQL and SQL Server are 2 completely different products.  Which one is this?

Comment: @Eric edited , that's my mistake

Comment: Is this a Navicat question or a database engine question? Where do you get the error?

Comment: @nicomp i get this error whenever i execute the first statement on the server , in navicat

Comment: @AaronBertrand I edited it already

Comment: Have you selected a database before you submit the SQL? How does Navicat know what database to query against?

Comment: @nicomp yes , this also occur on also my c# program , here is the connection string "server=x;database=7s;uid=username;pwd=password;" , and i still get the same error

Comment: Why would you expect the MySQL server to know which database to query against? You're not providing that information.

Comment: @nicomp because when i executed that command on my computer it worked . now for some reason it's giving me this mentioned error

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in MySQLWorkbench. As long as the server knows what database I am querying I don't need to qualify any columns with table names.

Comment: STORED (R); added in 5.7.6 (reserved) - have you changed versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored is a MySQL Reserved Word, so MySQL thinks you are intending to use that Reserved Word.

When you qualify it with the Table Name, then it knows what you are talking about.

UPDATE: You could wrap stored in back ticks (shown below) so it's treated as text and not a Reserved Word.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM camera WHERE `stored`=3;
```

Comment: Could you accomplish the same thing by writing `'stored'` (in back-quotes) when referring to the column name ? Just curious.

Comment: Thank You so much !!

Comment: @Ahmed Added an update for another option to keep in mind, using back ticks

Comment: Not quite stored is a RESERVED word therefore needs to be qualified, KEYWORDS don't need to be qualified.

Comment: Thanks to @Cascader too for adding the Select Statement.